# Import a binary image from matlab to a "C" program

Tags: c, matlab, binary

I have a binary image in Matlab, and I need the binary array(0 and 1) in a C program,
How can I import it?

I can save the binary image in Matlab as ".mat" but I don't know how to read the mat file in C.
Also I thought maybe I can save the binary image in Matlab as ".bin" which is readable in "C" but again I don't know how to save an image in matlab as ".bin".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also write your data to a binary file, which will be about twice smaller then text.

```
img=rand(10)>.5; %# an array from @Amro's answer
fid = fopen('test.bin','w');
fwrite(fid,img,'int8')
fclose(fid);
```

Then I believe you can read it in C without problems. Remember, MATLAB will write data by columns, not by rows - first 1st column, then 2nd, etc. If you want to read it in C by rows, just transpose the array before writing:

```
fwrite(fid,img','int8') %# notice ' symbol after img
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check the net using a searching engine. The place to search in first is of course Mathworks, where you can find docs like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf). The second step, since it looks complicated to write from scratch a converter, is to search if your need is already someone else need. A link like [this](http://www.mathworks.de/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f39876.html) could be useful, but there's the requirements of a MATLAB itself (linking with one of its libraries, the MAT-file interface library I suppose). I believe it is however the simpler thing to do.

The next simple solution is to use [this](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html) with a format we know we can read, *If the input array is of class logical, imwrite assumes the data is a binary image and writes it to the file with a bit depth of 1, if the format allows it. BMP, PNG, or TIFF formats accept binary images as input arrays.*

BMP images are not hard to be handled by custom routines; for PNG images, you can use png library, and for TIFF, I can't remember, but you can search or choose the other options.

[Here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/save.html) other ways of saving data are explained; a plain ascii file could be also easy to be parsed by custom C routines.

Answer (score 2):

```
>> img=rand(10)>.5
img =
     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
     0     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1
     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1
     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     0
     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0

>> dlmwrite('file.dat', img, 'delimiter',' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to export array data from Matlab and import it into a C program, one easy option (assuming the array isn't gigantic) is to use a plain text file as in intermediate.  From Matlab, write the array out as strings to a text file with each element separated by a comma (for example, `1,0,0,1,0,1,1,etc`).  Save this as a regular ASCII text file.  Now, you can open the file in C with `fopen`, read in a character at a time with `fgetc`, and reconstruct the array.

For example, the C portion might look like:

```
FILE* fp;
char  inp[3];
int   array[PLENTY_OF_ROOM], index=0;
fp = fopen("exported_data.txt", "r");
while (fgets(inp, 3, fp) != NULL) {
    if ((inp[0] == '0' || inp[0] == '1') && inp[1] == ',')
        array[index++] = inp[0] - '0';
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: bad format\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code I posted works for a row vector, but it should be easy enough to adapt for a 2D matrix (just add support for the detection and handling of the newline characters that would appear between rows).

Answer (score 0):

On some platforms (like Windows) you have to specify "binary" when opening the file, otherwise read/written bytes can be interpreted as special characters and may not be read/written to the file as expected:

```
FILE* fin,fout;
...
fin = fopen("file1.bin", "rb"); // the 'b' indicates "binary"   
fout = fopen("file1.bin", "wb"); // the 'b' indicates "binary"
```